# How to show multiple polylines in google maps ios sdk

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

1. here i used to get polylines API is https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=xxxxxxx&destination=xxxxxxxx

2.got the responce data and taken "overview_polyline" and showed one polyline on mapview.

3.now i want to draw multiple polylines between point 'A' to point 'B' location.

searched for alternates they given like https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

here how to generate a waypoints 'A' to 'B' location.

Comment: Can you please add some code how you are adding Polyline into GoogleMap ?

Comment: `let route = mapTasks.overviewPolyline["points"] as! String                        let path: GMSPath = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: route)!;
routePolyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path);
routePolyline.strokeColor = UIColor.blue;
routePolyline.strokeWidth = 2.0;
routePolyline.map = mapDirections`

Comment: No this one is for change property of polyline but how you are adding path and polyline into map while you got response from GoogleMapAPI?

Comment: here is my Api https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=sydney,au&destination=perth,au. i taken responce parsed **overview_polyline** string to   route object

Comment: i am adding path like above code, anything wrong in that.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add one Parameter to "&alternateroutes=true" this will give total number of route between two points